# No access to databases after login

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

I want to create a java interface for my database in sql server 2014, so I decided to make a connection with JDBC and I need to have user and password for connection, I've created a user but when I login with that user I have no access to the databases and even I cant create a database. I've searched but didn't find anything. I've found some posts about single user but it didnt work.

Comment: Please post jdbc connection code. Also, be sure to tag Java for the Java gurus to find your post and help.

Comment: @Parfait Here's the jdbc code, but i have problem with sql server, i get an error message in eclipse too, but i think it's because i dont have access to the databases in sql server.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, when you are creating a new user you should give permissions at that time:)